# Creating own universe/dimension/realm. As scientific as possible

Tags: science-based, physics

How can mankind or another very intelligent and developed race create their own universe/dimension/realm which is completely different from our universe (different physics equations, physics generally, dimensionality, topology, geometry and for example magic and other unbelievable things). Have we a theories that could answer this question as scientifically as possible? I hope that I set tags for this question properly because I had problem with it.

Comment: Anything with a hard science tag must obey the known laws of physics. You're specifically asking how to defy those laws, making the answer total speculation and outside the realm of hard science.

Comment: As far as we know, our world exists because [fundamental constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_constant) (speed of light,  gravitational constant, Planck's constant etc.) have certain specific values. Were they just little bit different, and the whole universe would be a whole lot different.

Comment: As this stands, it is far too broad. Please review https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: Greg Bear's novel Eon explored this very topic, and it is about as hard a "hard SF" novel as it is possible to find.

Comment: I can give you an example of a world that we create that is different that our own. Something simple like a video game. If you were a being that lived inside a video game, so long as the game is running it will all progress in accordance to the physics inside that world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

/create their own universe/dimension/realm /

If one considers such a realm to be an environment where different entities and objects interact according to preset rules, then various **virtual worlds** meet the criteria.  Even Zork.  These have rules for interaction which correspond to physical laws in the real world.  Virtual objects can exist.  People in things in the real world can exist as their avatars or projections into the virtual world.  You can purchase such a world for your game system and interact with it for days on end.  Is it as detailed as the real world?  Of course not.  Does the OP mandate that it must be?  No.

Would it be possible to have a real live person so immersed in the virtual world that interactions seem to that person much like what they are used to in the real world?  Of course this is a SF trope since Matrix and before.  I recently tried on one of those Oculus Rift headsets and the idea does not seem so zany to me anymore.